# Using excel find all possible combinations in five columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Using Excel, I want to find all possible combinations of 5 letters:

Say, in columns A-E I have the letters: a or A; b or B; c or C; d or D; e or E.

In column F, I want to display each combination. For example:

```
                       Combinations
a   b   c   d   e         abcde
A   B   C   D   E         Abcde
                          aBcde
                          abCde
```

Comment: With just your example, there's 3,628,800 possible combinations.  (If you just use lowercase or uppercase it's 120).  Is there some other reason for doing this? That's going to be a taxing process, which you'll need VBA for.

Comment: @BruceWayne I'm not looking for permutations - the order should be the same. Doesn't this mean there are 2^5 = 32 combinations?

Comment: Oh okay - I thought you meant any order too, sorry!  So for all ten letters though, it'd be 2^10 = 1024, since you could have ABCDE, aBCDE, abCDE, abcDE, etc...

Comment: @BruceWayne but in my case there are 32 combinations because there can only be 5 letters in each row in column F - right? Any ideas how to compute this easily?

Comment: Note that only one letter from each column can be used so there can't be A and a in the same row in column F

Comment: So, there really is nothing in the columns A-E, you just want column F to list all the possible combinations that could exist?

Comment: Or do you want the work to really be done in columns A-E and just do a simple concat in F?

Comment: @ExcelHero Thanks, I just want column F to list the combinations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the range `F1:F32`.

Paste the following formula into the Formula Bar:

```
=CHAR(CODE("a")-32*MID(DEC2BIN(ROWS($1:1)-1,5),1,1)) &
 CHAR(CODE("b")-32*MID(DEC2BIN(ROWS($1:1)-1,5),2,1)) &
 CHAR(CODE("c")-32*MID(DEC2BIN(ROWS($1:1)-1,5),3,1)) &
 CHAR(CODE("d")-32*MID(DEC2BIN(ROWS($1:1)-1,5),4,1)) &
 CHAR(CODE("e")-32*MID(DEC2BIN(ROWS($1:1)-1,5),5,1))
```

> This is **NOT** an array formula, but since multiple cells are selected, please confirm the formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Answer (score 0):

Well my off the bat solution would increment an integer from 0 to 32. Look at the first 5 bits of the binary of the integer. If the first bit is 0, use the first row for first letter. If 1, second row. Similar for the rest of the letters. The concatenation of these will give your combinations.